# SQL Server 2008 connecting error

Tags: sql-server-2008

After installation of SQL Server 2008, I open SQL Server 2008 and in `Connect to Server` window, I set following information :

- Server type: Database Engine
- Server name: `MATRIX-PC\SQLEXPRESS`
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
- User name: `MATRIX-PC\MATRIX`
- Password:

Note: my PC name is `MATRIX`

I also in above information Server name changed to `.\sqlexpress`, but it returns an error when click on connect button:

> Cannot connect to MATRIX-PC\SQLEXPRESS
>   Additional Information
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provide: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: If it's the only SQL server in your PC just but `.` on server name.

Comment: Which **edition** did you install? If you installed SQL Server 2008 **Express**, then the `.\SQLEXPRESS` (or `MATRIX\SQLEXPRESS`) should be OK, if you used all the default during installation. If you installed any other edition, then use just `.` (just a dot, or `MATRIX` as your PC is called) for the SQL Server instance name

Comment: Problem is not solved by me. Any other solution ?